# Spring boot NullPointerException after compile assembly:single and run, not when run from IDE

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, maven, build, nullpointerexception

I need advice about problem, with NullPointerException.
When I Run the project from IDE (Intel IJ) all running well (read/write DB PostgreSQL). But after `mvn compile assembly:single` (with dependencies) and run from terminal `java -jar fileName.jar` I get error NullPointerException with Repository interface. I creating it in config beans with `@Autowired` constructor in class.

Comment: So not use the maven-assembly-plugin to package your spring boot app use the spring-boot-maven-plugin configured in your build (pom.xml)...

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know about some source for learn configured the spring-boot-maven-plugin.

Comment: Check: https://start.spring.io/

Comment: I see that page, but when I used spring-boot-maven-plugin I get error "Source file must not be null", maybe problem with multimodule project?

Comment: I solved it. The problem was in other module, when miss one file. But when I run from IDE only one module, that was be OK. But when used spring-boot-maven-plugin, that crash on missing file in another modul.